# SQL Server does not exist or access denied from a VMWare guest

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, vmware

I've made the configuration to allow remote connections to SQL Server 2012, however I still cannot connect to it from a VMware Workstation Guest (using both NAT and Bridge).

I can ping the host machine from the guest VM when using NAT (the same is not true for bridge config).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure that the SQL Server IP address is listed in the IP Addresses page in TCP/IP protocol properties ( You can access it from SQL Server Configuration Manager )

[image]

Also be sure to restart SQL Server service after you do changes.

Comment: On top, make sure the firewall on the host is configured to let the traffic pass. This is not done automatically.